# Python NumPy Convert FFT To File

Tags: python, audio, filter, numpy, fft

I was wondering if it's possible to get the frequencies present in a file with NumPy, and then alter those frequencies and create a new WAV file from them? I would like to do some filtering on a file, but I have yet to see a way to read a WAV file into NumPy, filter it, and then *output the filtered version*. If anyone could help, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SciPy](http://scipy.org/) provides functions for [doing FFTs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html) on NumPy arrays, and also provides functions for [reading](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html#scipy.io.wavfile.read) and [writing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html#scipy.io.wavfile.write) them to WAV files. e.g.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft
import np as numpy

rate, input = read('input.wav')

transformed = rfft(input) 

filtered = function_that_does_the_filtering(transformed)
output = irfft(filtered)

write('output.wav', rate, output)
```

(`input`, `transformed` and `output` are all numpy arrays)

Comment: Does `scipy.io.wavfile` handle more than one audio channel?

Comment: @IainRist, It certainly handles them when writing: "To write multiple-channels, use a 2-D array of shape (Nsamples, Nchannels)" (presumably that means that it handles reading them too).

Comment: Just had a peek into the source. It does indeed reshape the data into correct number of channels.

Comment: Ah, perfect - I was hoping that NumPy could do this. I already outputted an array to a file, but wasn't sure how to go from a filtered signal to a file. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I've got a question now - I used the rfft() function to get the FFT analysis of the wave file, but the irfft() function doesn't give me the same sound wave back. It's going straight from being opened from a file to the rfft() function, and then into the irfft() function and is written to disk. Any ideas?

Comment: @SolarLune, without seeing the code, I'm not sure; it might be best if you asked a new question. (Are you basically doing `write('output.wav', rate, irfft(rfft(input)))`? if so, I have no idea what would be going on.)

Comment: @Iain Rist I believe I'm doing that exactly. (For some reason Stack Overflow messes with the format (just spacing things out) in these replies), but this is pretty much what I've got:

filtereddata = numpy.fft.rfft(data[:])
filteredwrite = numpy.fft.irfft(filtereddata)
wavfile.write('.TestFiltered.wav', rate, filteredwrite)